# Using legacy Rails DB with new Rails 7 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a legacy rails application that has been upgraded over the years from (Rails 2 to 5). My thought is instead of upgrading the existing application to Rails 7 then migrating to use Hotwire/Stimulus, I'd like to build a new application, start fresh but use the existing DB.

Are there any tutorials that go through the steps of doing this? I found a lot that talk about migrating to a Rails application w/ a legacy DB.

Comment: Hey Arash, there's no canonical guide to what you're asking, there's probably a tutorial somewhere, google is your friend there. It's really not going to be any different than the tutorials on migrating to a Rails app w/ a legacy DB. I'm voting to close because this is like to result in very opinion-based answers.

Comment: It depends on how big the app is and how well-tested it is. If you have good test coverage, I would migrate the app. But don't go from straight from V5 to V7, do one minor version at a time, and watch for deprecation warnings as you go.